# (standard-in) 1: Syntax error when using bc

Tags: shell-script, bc

I have this command that works correct. However it shows a (standard_in) 1: Syntax error that I don't know how to identify.

```
participants=0
while IFS=, read -r id name nat sex date height weight sport gold silver bronze info; do
if [[ $(echo "$height>=0.1 && $height<=$2 && $weight>=0.1 && $weight<=$3" | bc) -eq 1 ]] ; then
let participants++
fi
echo -e $participants
done < $1
```

Can someone help me in order to identify my error?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your variables (`$height`, `$weight`, `$2` or `$3`) is either empty or is not a valid number.

```
$ echo "6>=5" | bc
1

# First operand is not a number
$ echo "6x>=5" | bc
(standard_in) 1: syntax error

# First operand is empty
$ echo ">=5" | bc
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

For debugging purposes, I suggest to `echo` those variables before you perform the `bc`. That way you'll be able to see which of the variables don't contain valid numbers.

```
participants=0
while IFS=, read -r id name nat sex date height weight sport gold silver bronze info; do

  echo "\$height='$height' \$weight='$weight' \$2='$2' \$3='$3'"
  # Or:
  echo "Going echo the following to bc: $height>=0.1 && $height<=$2 && $weight>=0.1 && $weight<=$3"

  if [[ $(echo "$height>=0.1 && $height<=$2 && $weight>=0.1 && $weight<=$3" | bc) -eq 1 ]] ; then
    let participants++
  fi
  echo -e $participants
done < $1
```